# how to see the python api doc in pycharm ipython notebook

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I am developing ipython notebook in pycharm. But I don't know how to check the python doc of the library I use in the notebook with IDE support (like mouse over the code and python api doc display automatically). Does anyone know that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution - print somewhere `__doc__` or use LPM when clicking on method you want to check to go directly to the file, where method you need is declared. Then you should have docstring of it.

Comment: Actually I want IDE support rather than using __doc__